# Licensing of Financial Force

Tags: administration, licenses, userlicense, financialforce

Does anyone have a reliable source of information on **Financial Force licensing**, what each license controls, where you set that license or "addition to a license", etc?

The have multiple references for the SAME THING in different places; some of them talk about "PSA" which apparently has nothing to do with our licensing; our Contract shows licenses for:

- FFA
- FFR
- FFRM

...but they are incapable of sending me details on what exactly each license, found under Manage Licenses in the installed application page, does. And, their Contract has completely different references:

- Full Accounting (I would presume is FFA?)
- Executive Accounting (may be part of FFA?)
- 360 CRM for FFA (presumably part of FFA?)
- Platform Accounting (might just be SF Platform licenses for those who don't need a full SF license?)

So, FFR and FFRM are nowhere on our Contract. We have xx licenses in all three areas to assign, and the number of the first three line items above equals xx.

My only "guess" at this point is: They do not actually CONTROL that second list. That we contracted for those "assumed" amounts of "those types of users", but we get "all inclusive" licenses (the first list) which means technically ALL USERS can do ALL FUNCTIONALITY of FFA, and/or FFR, and/or FFRM.

So:

1. Does anyone know of documentation explaining the exact areas in SF/FF each of the FIRST LIST ITEMS gets access to?
2. Same question, but about the SECOND LIST above?

Historical:   I've spent close to THREE WEEKS trying to get the answer to this, and every single person who gets involved from FF gives me DIfFERENT information AND NEW TERMINOLOGY (just got informed we also have "xx RevRec" licenses - I'm GUESSING that is the FFRM license, but really don't know).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best I can tell you is:

FFA - FinancialForce Accounting

- https://www.financialforce.com/financial-management/accounting/

FFR - FinancialForce Reporting

- FinancialForce custom reporting application for FFA

FFRM - FinancialForce Revenue Management

> FinancialForce Revenue Management:  Revenue Management provides a
>   robust tool for any customer to handle all of their revenue
>   recognition and revenue forecasting needs.  Revenue Management
>   provides a number of standard templates along with the ability to
>   define revenue recognition rules.

- https://www.financialforce.com/financial-management/revenue-recognition-management/

Any user needing access to any feature of one of those packages will need a license assigned to them...

Additionally there are permission sets for each package (a lot of them) that will need to be assigned based on the users role in the organization that gives them specific access based on job role...

You assign the licenses in salesforce via

> Setup -> Installed Packages

Then next to the particular package click **Manage Licenses** and follow the prompts

Comment: What I found fascinating in my investigation (including discussion with two different employees at FF who told me different thigns) is that... FF uses the honor system, plain and simple.   :-P  So does Rootstock.  Could they "check on things" and say "hey, you're using more than you paid for!".  Probably.  The second person claimed they don't do that.  (shrug)  Silly.

Answer (score 0):

Does this document help at all? https://1x8clt34ex4l3nepm7b15t5f-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/assets/downloads/pdf/legal/FF-Product-Usage-Terms-20181109.pdf It's clear as mud to me.